# I can't print the PHP POST

Tags: php, postman

I have a file test.php

But if a use the postman app and choose POST option 
http://127.0.0.1/sge/test.php?value=1255455
I have an empty array
If I change the file and the postman require to $_GET, it works
I changed (enable_post_data_reading = on) in php.ini
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Post the related code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Luis, when you pass the parameters in your URL you're using the GET method, not the POST method, sou you'll only be able to print your $_GET.

You can create a form at your page, set its method="POST" and action to the same page or another one, and then print the $_POST contents there.

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php"> ....... </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `POST` method right. You're now using the HTTP method `POST`, but you are using the URL parameters to pass in values, which is for the `GET` method.

When you look at postman you should see something like this:

[image]

When you press *Body*, you will be able to enter keys and values which will be sent through the `POST` method. You can then print these values out using `$_POST`